# Как сделать загрузку файлов по url в telegram?

Tags: javascript, json, telegram-bot, api

Get-запрос формирует json, в котором указан url на скачку mp3 файла. Я начал гуглить как это сделать и до конца не понял, что именно нужно искать. Наткнулся на fetch, но не понял, то ли я нашел? Fetch загружает файлы на сервер как я понял, а мне нужно в телегу. И тут вот загвоздка, что мне в итоге надо гуглить, и что почитать по этому поводу. Дали задание, а я вообще до этого не занимался веб-программированием, но нужно сделать. Если подробнее, то пытаюсь выгрузить mp3 из этого api: https://zadarma.com/ru/support/api/#api_pbx_record_request

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мой главный вопрос в том, что в итоге мне нужно искать. Fetch подходит для моих задач?